# Is every topological space is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Actually I am learning about measure theory. But I have confusion between  topological space and measurable . Is there any relationship among them or not?

Comment: I don't think there is any relationship between them...

Comment: I prefer to think about it this way.  A set $X$ could have two very different structures on it, e.g., a group (or a vector space) as well as a topology (or a metric).   There does not *have* to be any relationship between them as far as the definitions go.  But in every important and natural instance there always is a relationship.  For group + topology you would want the group operations to be continuous in the topology.  For measurable space + topological space you would want the open sets to be measurable.  You get a nice theory when the two structures pay attention to each other.

Answer (score 4):

The two are unrelated mathematical structures. However, every topological space can be given a particular useful $\sigma$-algebra, called the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. This is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets of the space. One useful property is that continuous real-valued functions are measurable with respect to this $\sigma$-algebra. More generally, if $X,Y$ are topological spaces, and you equip them both with their Borel $\sigma$-algebras, then continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ are measurable.

The most commonly used $\sigma$-algebras are the Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for each $n$. These are not the Borel $\sigma$-algebras of these spaces. However, every Lebesgue measurable set is the union of a Borel set and a subset of a Borel set of measure zero.